# How do I use the same keymap for different commands depending on the file type?

Tags: vim, neovim

I have the following config, but when I enter an eruby file and then go back to a different file, F3 still executes `:Autoformat`.

```
noremap <F3> :Neoformat<CR>
autocmd FileType eruby bufdo map <F3> :Autoformat<CR>
```

I want it to only apply that command while in eruby buffers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, don’t use `bufdo` here; it executes a command for all buffers. Second, prefer `<buffer>` mappings.

With autocommands:

```
augroup vimrc_eruby
  au!
  au FileType eruby noremap <buffer> <F3> :Autoformat<CR>
augroup END
```

But I highly encourage reading about `ftplugin`s, and using `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/eruby.vim`. Read about `setlocal`, `map-<buffer>`, and `b:undo_ftplugin` in vim’s help.

I’ve written answers about using these tools on Vi & Vim StackExchange a few times: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22256/10604, https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15329/10604, https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15019/10604

Comment: Thanks for your help! I actually added bufdo as a last shot before asking for help, which didn't help. I did read about ftplugins, but what I found on Google seemed like they might not work well with neovim.

Comment: @Brandon they ought to; the path just might be different (`~/.config/nvim` instead of `~/.vim`)